# check if encoding exist?

Tags: .net, character-encoding

```
abc = Encoding.GetEncoding("xyz"); //Throws exception if xyz non existing.
```

Is there a way to tryget encoding or do you have to catch the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Encoding.GetEncodings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings.aspx) first, and then try to find one matching the name:

```
var encodingInfo = Encoding.GetEncodings()
                           .FirstOrDefault(info => info.Name == targetName);

if (encodingInfo != null)
{
    Encoding encoding = encodingInfo.GetEncoding();
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

If you do this regularly, you may well want to build a dictionary of name/encoding once, and then use `TryGetValue` on that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Encoding.GetEncodings()` method. The method returns all available encodings. You may then look up for the encoding in the returned array.